# SQL Server : nonstandard query

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table `dzialki_wlasciciele`

```
id_dzialki | id_wlasc  | id_malz  |  
    1      |   1       |  2
    1      |   2       |  1
    2      |   1       |  2
    3      |   1       |  2
```

Now I need two queries - one to return two rows where `id_dzialki = 1` (where it has two `id_wlasc` where `id_wlasc` of second row = `id_malz` of first row)

And second query should return `id_dzialki = 2 and = 3` (where there is no second record  where  `id_wlasc = id_malz`)

Second question I have :

```
select * 
from dzialki_wlasciciele dw1 
where dw1.ID_WLASC = 1 
  and dw1.id_dzialki not in (select dw2.id_dzialki 
                             from dzialki_wlasciciele dw2 
                             where ID_malz = 1)
```

But how about first question ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
DECLARE @dzialki_wlasciciele TABLE
    (
      id_dzialki INT ,
      id_wlasc INT ,
      id_malz INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @dzialki_wlasciciele
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 2 ),
        ( 1, 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, 2 ),
        ( 3, 1, 2 )


SELECT  d1.*
FROM    @dzialki_wlasciciele d1
        JOIN @dzialki_wlasciciele d2 ON d2.id_dzialki = d1.id_dzialki
                                        AND d2.id_wlasc = d1.id_malz
WHERE   d1.id_dzialki = 1
```

Output:

```
id_dzialki  id_wlasc    id_malz
1           1           2
1           2           1
```

Comment: But there is one problem - I don't know id_dzialki (this must return query). I  know (can send to query) only id_wlasc and id_malz

Comment: remove `WHERE   d1.id_dzialki = 1` and you will get all pairs that satisfy your conditions

Comment: I try  query  where d1.id_wlasc=1   insteed of id_dzialki =1 but it return only row with id_wlasc=1  and id_dzialki=1 but no second row with id_wlasc =2 and id_dzialki=1 :(